# Can a class in C# 6.0 have a protected primary constructor?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

This class:

```
class Person 
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        _firstName = FirstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
    }

    private readonly string _firstName; // Make it really immutable
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
    }

    private readonly string _lastName; // Make it really immutable
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Can be rewritten in C# [version 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn683793.aspx) with a **primary** constructor as:

```
class Person(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    public string FirstName { get; } = firstName;
    public string LastName { get; } = lastName;
}
```

Is it possible to give the primary constructor a different modifier like in the following class?

```
abstract class Person 
{
    protected Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        _firstName = FirstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
    }

    private readonly string _firstName; // Make it really immutable
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
    }

    private readonly string _lastName; // Make it really immutable
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532233/protected-vs-public-constructor-for-abstract-class-is-there-a-difference

Comment: I don't I understand the use-case, if you make your class abstract, it doesn't matter if the constructor is public or not as you would have to inherit the class anyway, giving you access to the constructor.

Comment: @FaisalShah You refer to a question with an normal C# version 5 or lower constructor. Not a primaray constructor.

Comment: @AlexSiepman do you mean for having a `public static` method for construction?

Comment: If you leave it as public, then people still can't call it since you can't instantiate an abstract class.  You would still only be able to call it from a subclass.  Doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: @KyleW This a good point. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew You are right. But the same problem would be to have a private constructor or to have a private constructor when the class is not abstract.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer talks about pre-release version of C# 6.0. The final release version of C# 6.0 doesn't have primary constructors at all.

---

[The Language Design Notes for 21 April](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/543876) say (and I didn't find any later reference to this):

> ## Separate accessibility on type and primary constructor
>
> There are scenarios where you don’t want the constructors of your type to have the same accessibility as the type. A common case is where the type is public, but the constructor is private or protected, object construction being exposed only through factories.
>
> Should we invent syntax so that a primary constructor can get a different accessibility than its type?
>
> ### Conclusion
>
> No. There is no elegant way to address this. This is a fine example of a scenario where developers should just fall back to normal constructor syntax. With the previous decisions above, we’ve done our best to make sure that that cliff isn’t too steep.

So, no, there is no way to declare the primary constructor as `protected`. Though, as was already pointed out, there is no difference between `public` and `protected` constructor for an `abstract` class.

Answer (score 5):

No, the primary constructor definition syntax defaults many characteristics of the constructor:

- It's always public
- It never has anything in the body except for member initialization (it appears that this varies between different preview versions, and no one yet knows what will be in the final C# 6.0 specification)
- The same base constructor will be called from all constructors of the derived class (because the rest forward to the primary constructor)

etc.

(This discusses a feature that is not yet released, it might change in other versions)

Comment: That's not completely true... There is a way to specify constructor body for primary constructor... Also primary constructor can be `internal` or `private`, as long as the entire class has the same access modifier...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I believe that this is also not completely true. You can have a single private constructor and the class can be public.

Comment: But can the private constructor by primary constructor?

Answer (score 5):

Primary constructor shares access modifier with a class, so you can make it `public` or  `internal`, **as long as class you're declaring it has the same access level**. You can't have `public` class with `internal` or `protected` primary constructor.

However, in your case even when constructor is `public` noone will be able to call it directly, because your class is `abstract` and you cannot instantiate an abstract class. You have to instantiate class that inherits it and is not `abstract` either.

**PS** I know it's not part of the question, but I see that's you've already accepted an answer which includes additional information about primary constructors, that is not true. **Primary constructor can have body!**

> (... ) it is possible to specify a primary constructor body simply by
>   enclosing it in curly braces inside of the declared type:
>
> ```
> public class Customer(string first, string last)
> {
>     {
>         if (first == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
>         if (last == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("last");
>     }
>
>     public string First { get; } = first;
>     public string Last { get; } = last;
> }
> ```

You can read more about new C# features on [Roslyn page on codeplex](http://roslyn.codeplex.com), e.g. in this document: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status

Comment: I could not get the example working. Can you add a link to the documentation of C# 6 that discribes the how the primary constructor can have body?

Comment: There is no spec yet. Check the last link in my answer. IT might be that your VS version does not support it yet.

Comment: The new features of CTP 3 (expression-bodied function members, nameof operator, Null-conditional statement expressions) still not worked for me either. Maybe I need the CTP 3 version working on my Visual Studio to get he the empty body working.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: There are a lot of versions of C# running around developed since VS 2013 was released, and **none of them are C# 6.0**

Comment: I've made [a meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269576/103167) to deal with the situation.

Comment: No, [primary constructor in a `private` class behaves as if it was `public`, not `private`](https://gist.github.com/svick/5e60c304ee73598f93f3) (tested in VS 14 CTP 3).

Comment: I could finally get CTP 3 working, and have the primary constructor working with a body. Thankx for the info.